# 403 Forbidden error in Firefox only, works in Chrome and Safari

Tags: firefox

I have a Firefox quicksearch bookmark that runs a Maxmind query. This worked until recently. I type 'ip 82.176.230.15' (for example) into the URL bar and it queries Maxmind to retrieve the location of the IP:

http://www.maxmind.com/app/locate_demo_ip?ips=82.176.230.15

Within the past week, for reasons unknown, I now get a 403/Forbidden error when I try to access Maxmind.

"You don't have permission to access /app/locate_demo_ip on this server"

Strangely, the same URL is accessible in Chrome and Safari. I can also access the same URL with Firefox, Chrome, or Safari on my Mac.

I've deleted all cookies, disabled all addons, and still can't get it to work. Any idea what could be happening? I know that the 403 has to come from the server, so I don't know why it would work in other browsers. And it's been going on for days, definitely not some glitch on their server.

Comment: Is there a proxy between you and the web? It could be doing some kind of strange caching. Further more it works for me in Firefox - are you sure there isn't an error/typo/corruption in your bookmark?

Comment: Yes @Lee, I have [the same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807123/forbidden-403-cached-in-squid-proxy) and it appears when squid proxy is in place!

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same issue and was able to fix it.
In my case the problem was in headers that Mozilla sent.
Particularly it was because of header:

```
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:100.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0"
```

What makes web-site refuse connection is this part of string "(X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:100.0)" and i have no idea why.

I found a nice solution, you can change Mozilla settings to include other browsers in this header (Chrome and Safari) and it could make sites with this problem works.

Here is how to do it:

1. Type `about:config` into the URL bar. Press Enter.
2. Create a new entry with `key=general.useragent.override` and add this string there `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.115 Safari/537.36`. I found that Google Chrome uses this string as User-Agent header probably to prevent such issues. So you should see something like:
   [image]
3. Now save this settings and go reload your page, it should work now

Answer (score 0):

Get an HTTP debugger like firebug or fiddler (not sure that will work with FireFox, but probably if you set it up right)

Look at the difference between using your quick bookmark and just typing the URL.  The server could return 403 whenever it feels like -- see if there's any difference, and what it is.

Comment: Thanks Lou. Copy+pasting the URL didn't make a difference vs using the bookmark. I upgraded Firefox to 3.6.13 (I was on 3.6.8) and now it works as expected. Still a bit confusing because upgrading doesn't usually change your prefs. Maybe there was some setting within Firefox that was reset when I upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

Wonderful observation from the answer by @Vlad! This was my issue too. For a weird reason my website is suddenly not opening on Firefox. I initially thought it was the router, but then I changed the network and the problem was still persistent, even though the site could work on other devices or in another browser. Firefox Private mode also did not work.

At the end, I installed the `User-Agent Switcher` Firefox extension as was suggested at this [link](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-reset-default-user-agent-firefox). I added a custom user-agent string which modified my original one slightly from `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:113.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/113.0` to `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:113.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0` and that was actually enough to make the site work again. I'll have to later check the site internals to see what could be causing this permission denial.