# Forbidden 403 - cached in squid proxy?

Tags: http, .htaccess, proxy, http-status-code-403, squid

It seems that squid proxy somehow remembers the `403 Forbidden` response and remembers it even if you reload the page which is already accessible.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Put some restriction to .htaccess (like `deny from all`). Open in browser, connected via squid proxy, error 403 appears.
2. Remove the restriction from .htaccess.
3. Reload the page - the error 403 is still present!

Comment: Well ... try adding appropriate caching headers when sending 403 response to prevent caching of those pages (if you can, of course -- depends who generates those 403 -- your script or web server itself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [negative_ttl](http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/v2/2.7/cfgman/negative_ttl.html) parameter.

Comment: thanks, but it is not apparent from your answer (and the linked docs) how to set it, if you want to completely switch off the cache in this case.

Comment: I set `negative_ttl 0` and it does the job.